# Android Studio Bluetooth emulators

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am currently trying to create my first app.  I am currently attempting to use Android Studio. I am running into a lot of questions that I cannot seem to find on the internet.

Is it possible to use multiple emulators (to simulate phones) to connect to one emulator using Bluetooth?

I think I understand the code involved, I know a little bit of Java and there is some open source for connecting to a device Via Bluetooth.  I figured I can just open up one emulator and search for the other ones via Bluetooth.

**EDIT to post a question to an answer:**

If there is no way to simulate the connection of multiple devices by Bluetooth with an emulator...Would this mean there is no "virtual" way to simulate a Bluetooth connection? If that is true it would require me to use physical hardware...

The only way to try my app out would be: to use physical phones, upload my "app" to multiple physical devices and see if they can connect..Does that sound like the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no emulators support Bluetooth. As such, you cannot simulate the connection of multiple devices to a single emulator.